# Adding a status bar UI lollipop 5.1.1

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, notification-bar

I'm quite new to modding android UI.I recently bought an android tv box, the firmware doesn't have status bar enabled, is there any way to create one or port one from another rom and which of the system file would I need to modify to do the job? It's just a stock 5.1.1 firmware but has NO pull down or status bar.

Any help very much appreciated 
Andy =)